# Runtime exception when functional test running

Tags: testing, playframework

```
public class MyTest extends FunctionalTest {

    @Test
    public void gtest() {
        Http.Response response = GET("http://google.com"); // <--- RuntimeException
        assertIsOk(response);
        assertContentType("text/html", response);
        assertCharset("utf-8", response);
    }
}
```

This code throw :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.makeRequest(FunctionalTest.java:299)
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.makeRequest(FunctionalTest.java:305)
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.GET(FunctionalTest.java:103)
    at play.test.FunctionalTest.GET(FunctionalTest.java:57)
    at MyTest.gtest(MyTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Can u tell why this error occurs ? And how to fix it? Playframework 1.2.4 / Java 1.7.0_02.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to increase your execution pool size, which is by default 1 in `dev` mode (which also means `test`, by default). You're running out of threads and thus the exception occurs.

Try with a setting like this in your `application.conf`:

```
%test.play.pool=2
```